How to query all the ID of the first table with the last Event and the first Date on the second table related one-to-many to the first?
I'm trying to retrieve from two tables related one-to-many (Subattivita.ID-Eventi-IDSubattivita), some fields from first table and two other fields to the second table (last Eventi.Evento and first Eventi.DataInserimento).
I don't know why I get an error with the following SQL query.
Can someone help, please?
First Table: Subattivita



ID
Contenuto




1
Prova


2
Prova2


3
Prova3


4
prova4


5
Prova5


6
Prova6


7
prova7


9
Realizzare disegno


10
Prova8



Second Table: Eventi



ID
IDSubattivita
Evento
Commento
DataInserimento




1
1
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
01/08/2024


2
2
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
01/08/2024


3
3
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
01/08/2024


4
4
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
01/08/2024


5
5
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
02/08/2024


8
6
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
02/08/2024


9
7
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
02/08/2024


12
9
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
02/08/2024


13
10
Aperta
Inserimento automatico
02/08/2024


14
1
Remarks
Testo1
05/08/2024


15
2
Remarks
Testo2
05/08/2024


16
3
Remarks
Testo3
06/08/2024


17
4
Remarks
Testo4
06/08/2024


18
5
Remarks
Testo5
07/08/2024


19
6
Remarks
Testo8
08/08/2024


20
7
Remarks
Testo9
09/08/2024


21
9
Remarks
Testo12
09/08/2024


22
9
Remarks
Procedi con disegno.
09/08/2024


23
9
Caricata
Disegno caricato.
09/08/2024


24
9
Chiusa
Disegno approvato
09/08/2024



Required results of query:



ID
LastEvento
FirstDataInserimento




1
Remarks
01/08/2024


2
Remarks
01/08/2024


3
Remarks
01/08/2024


4
Remarks
01/08/2024


5
Remarks
02/08/2024


6
Remarks
02/08/2024


7
Remarks
02/08/2024


9
Chiusa
02/08/2024


10
Aperta
02/08/2024



I've tried with the following SQL query, but Access asks to enter the u.Evento value:
SELECT 
    t.ID, 
    u.Evento as LastEvento, 
    p.DataInserimento as FirstDataInserimento
FROM 
    ((Subattivita t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT IDSubattivita, MAX(ID) as MaxID FROM Eventi GROUP BY IDSubattivita) u ON t.ID = u.IDSubattivita)
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT IDSubattivita, MIN(ID) as MinID FROM Eventi GROUP BY IDSubattivita) p ON t.ID = p.IDSubattivita);



If you get an error, share that error.

WHAT error do you get?  I can see right away that your p table does not include a DataInserimento field, and your u table does not include an Evento field.  Both of those only contain two columns.

I've made some edits, and added Access message.

That's not an error message. It is a prompt from query for input of value because query references field(s) not in dataset - as noted by @TimRoberts. Looks like you want the Min(DataInserimento) for each IDSubattivita. Pulling Evento associated with maximum ID for each IDSubattivita is more complicated. Consider:
SELECT Q.IDSubattivita, Evento AS LastEvento, FirstDataInserimento FROM Eventi INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Eventi.IDSubattivita, Max(Eventi.ID) AS EID, 
     Min(Eventi.DataInserimento) AS FirstDataInserimento FROM Eventi
     GROUP BY Eventi.IDSubattivita) AS Q 
ON Eventi.ID=Q.EID;

Or this version:
SELECT Subattivita.ID, Contenuto, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 Evento FROM Eventi AS Dup 
    WHERE IDSubattivita=Subattivita.ID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS LastEvento, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 DataInserimento FROM Eventi AS Dup WHERE 
    IDSubattivita=Subattivita.ID ORDER BY ID) AS FirstDataInserimento
FROM Subattivita;


Hi June7, your help is much appreciated (twice answers to two questions!).
Now seems so easy and obvious, but I hadn't been able to find the right SQL query.

(I prefer the second version)
Thank you!
